# Change default certificate manager for libreoffice

Tags: libreoffice, default-programs

In libreoffice
File > Digital signatures
Brings up a dialog box where I can choose "Start certificate manager"

Clicking it opens "seahorse passwords and keys" application.
**I want to tweak the LibreOffice to open "keystore explorer" instead of "seahorse"**

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Same request. LibreOffice deals with Seahorse but you cannot import PKCS#12 certificate in Seahorse. Keystore Explorer seems to be a much better X509 certificate manager.